# How do I calculate the attenuation per distance of a sound wave with sharp directivity?

Tags: acoustics

In general, I think that the inverse square law according to distance in acoustics is due to the field created by the point source. How do you calculate the sound pressure level according to the distance when considering a directional sound source (or beam forming by array) rather than omnidirectional? Do you need to know the beam width and estimate the parametric value by introducing the cube angle concept?

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**: The inverse square law holds for 3-dimensional sources, regardless of the directivity pattern.

**Explanation**:

The directivity pattern is usually defined in the far field, or several wavelengths/source radii away from the source.  At this distance the waves that started at the source are all out-propagating (or are to a very good approximation).  Thus, they are also spreading over space.  Think of it this way: if your directivity pattern is consistent over space, moving from 10 m to 20 m from the source reduces the energy density by half, just as it would for a completely omnidirectional source.  The inverse square law still holds in the far field.  (In fact, you could define the "far-field" as the distance from a source in 3D at which the inverse square law is appropriate.)

Comment: Thank for your kind explanation. I agree your advice. Longing for..